# Javascript Upload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function to upload. In HTML I have 3 boxes created to insert the images, however when I choose some images to upload, it does not fill me the first 3 boxes (the ones created in HTML) and creates others after those 3.
Does anyone know the reason? I always want to insert in the 3 that are created, if you choose 4 it just has to create 1 more.

[image: Problem]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hefty95/pen/yLLVjGX)

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('pro-image').addEventListener('change', readImage, false);

  $(".preview-images-zone").sortable();

  $(document).on('click', '.image-cancel', function() {
    let no = $(this).data('no');
    $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + no).remove();
  });
});

var num = 4;

function readImage() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
    var output = $(".preview-images-zone");

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

      var picReader = new FileReader();

      picReader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        var picFile = event.target;
        var html = '<div class="preview-image preview-show-' + num + '">' +
          '<div class="image-cancel" data-no="' + num + '">x</div>' +
          '<div class="image-zone"><img id="pro-img-' + num + '" src="' + picFile.result + '"></div>' + '</div>';

        output.append(html);
        num = num + 1;
      });

      picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    $("#pro-image").val('');
  } else {
    console.log('Browser not support');
  }
}
```

Comment: @A1rPun You can use my codepen link. However I will put a picture to explain.

Comment: The reason they are added to the output and not replacing the already created placeholders is because you always do `output.append(html)`. You have to create some logic if the placeholders are full, then create new divs with `output.append(html)`.

Comment: @A1rPun It can not be. I can open even in anonymous mode

Comment: Strange, I can not understand why he does not insert in the first :(

Comment: You `append`! That is not the same as inserting into div with class `preview-show-1`!

Comment: @A1rPun Using codepen, if you click the upload button and select 4 images, you will understand my problem

Comment: Oh I do understand your problem, I even see more and know how to fix all of them but you have to understand that you already created some divs in HTML and you are always appending to the output, not replacing the divs that are already there.

Comment: You're right and I already realize the problem, but is there any way for me to replace the ones that are already created? Basically the divs created in html serve as page design, I just wanted to insert uploaded files in them, hence the HTML

Comment: Yes that is an option but it will not cover your problem with the `num` variable that keeps counting up. If you delete an image you can't know which number to replace anymore. You have to refactor your code to have an array of images and then display it HTML. Don't try to put your **state** in HTML, try to keep it in JavaScript and if an image is added you can render the HTML again.

Comment: @A1rPun i use prepend() and works ! that is the right solution?

Comment: @A1rPun Thanks, u opened my eyes

Comment: `prepend()` is UX wise a good choice! You still have the problem of the static HTML content but from the looks of it you are on your way to solve it ;)

Comment: You're right, he doesn't fill in the first ones but adds more empty boxes ... now I really have no idea how I can fix this

Comment: Uploading images is a deceptive hard task. I usually let a library handle this task for me. To fix your code I can create an answer.

Comment: I would be really grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code you can make the following changes:

```
var num = 1;

function readImage() {
    // ...
    $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + num).remove();
    output.prepend(html);
    // ...
}
```

If you remove all images you'll end up in a state where there are no placeholders anymore, I'm not sure if this is desired.

**Edit**

I found a way using your code to get the desired result of always having 3 placeholders. Remove all placeholders in HTML and use this JS code:

```
var output = $(".preview-images-zone");
var num = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  document
    .getElementById("pro-image")
    .addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
  output.append(createNewPreview(num++));
  output.append(createNewPreview(num++));
  output.append(createNewPreview(num++));
  output.sortable();

  $(document).on("click", ".image-cancel", function() {
    removePreview($(this).data("no"));
  });
});

function removePreview(n) {
  if (n) {
    $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + n).remove();
  } else if ($(".preview-image").length > 3) {
    const placeholders = $(".preview-image img:not([src])");
    if (placeholders.length) {
      placeholders
        .eq(0)
        .closest(".preview-image")
        .remove();
    }
  }

  if ($(".preview-image").length < 3) {
    output.append(createNewPreview(num++));
  }
}

function createNewPreview(id, src) {
  return $(
    `<div class="preview-image preview-show-${id}">
  <div class="image-cancel" data-no="${id}">x</div>
  <div class="image-zone"><img id="pro-img-${id}" ${
      src ? `src="${src}"` : ""
    }></div>
</div>`
  );
}

function readImage() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
    var output = $(".preview-images-zone");

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      if (!file.type.match("image")) continue;

      var picReader = new FileReader();

      picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        output.prepend(createNewPreview(num, event.target.result));
        num++;
        removePreview();
      });

      picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    $("#pro-image").val("");
  } else {
    console.log("Browser not support");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way when removing all images to have the placeholders?

Comment: Can you add this to your reply to complete the post successfully? Thank you very much for your attention  !

Comment: @Dinho I modified my answer to get the desired result. Didn't save it on codepen but it is easily reproducible.